# angular2 testing - Input text change doesn't affect on ngmodel

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set a DOM input element through angular2 test.:

Here is the HTML code:

```
<div>
            <label for="Player X">Player X</label>
            <input type="text" id="playerX" required [(ngModel)]="players[0].id" name="playerXid">
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="Player O">Player O</label>
            <input type="text" id="playerO" required [(ngModel)]="players[1].id" name="playerOid">
        </div>
```

Here is the test code, which fails because `players[0].id` and `players[1].id` are empty:

```
it('Test input <-> player bindings', () => {
        fixture.detectChanges();

        let playerX = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#playerX');
        playerX.value = 'First';
        playerX.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));
        let playerO = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement.querySelector('#playerO');
        playerO.value = 'Second';
        playerO.dispatchEvent(new Event('input'));

        fixture.detectChanges();

        expect(comp.players[0].id).toBe('First');
        expect(comp.players[1].id).toBe('Second');
     });
```

What am I missing here ?

**UPDATE**

I've realized that input value DOES get updated.
Issue is that `comp.players` doesn't!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
let playerX = compiled.querySelector('#playerX');
let player0 = compiled.querySelector('#playerX');

fixture.detectChanges();

// Change value
playerX.value = 'First';
player0.value = 'Second';

// dispatch input event
dispatchEvent(playerX, 'input');
dispatchEvent(player0, 'input');
```

Let me know...

Comment: dispatchEvent should get Event type as a parameter:

dispatchEvent(evt:Event) : Boolean